# How to find a user selection weather forward or backward in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am new to javascript.I am trying to make an simple toggle up div With user selection direction ill place the toggle div.After some googling I found one working fiddle But not as expected See the below screenshot to see the difference

When I select Some text on the front of the paragraph It works fine Like this

[image]

But when I selected some text from bottom paragraph It is not Working as expected
[image]

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCwwN/)

Actually I am working in React version Fiddle is in Jquery

This is my code

```
    import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom';

export default class App extends  React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            display:'none'  ,
            top:'',
            bottom:'',
            left:'',
            right:'',
            diplayForDown:'none'

        };
        this.handleOnMouseDown = this.handleOnMouseDown.bind(this)
        this.onMounseUp = this.onMounseUp.bind(this)
        this.onMouseDwn = this.onMouseDwn.bind(this)
        this.triggerAlltime = this.triggerAlltime.bind(this)
    }

    handleOnMouseDown(){
        let sel = window.getSelection && window.getSelection();

        let r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
        let relative=document.body.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log('Relative ',relative);

    if(!sel.isCollapsed){

        console.log(sel,r);
        let display = 'block';

        let top = (r.bottom - relative.top - 80)+'px';
        let bottom = r.bottom+'px';
        let left =( r.left)+'px';
        let right = (r.right)+'px';
        console.log('This is Height',r.bottom-r.top);
        let selectionHeight = r.bottom - r.top;
        if(selectionHeight => 22.22){
            this.setState({
                display,
                top:top,
                bottom,
                left,
                right
            })
        }else{
            this.setState({
                display,
                top,
                bottom,
                left,
                right
            })
        }


    }else{
        this.setState({
            display:'none'
        })
    }






        console.log('Slected')
    }
    onMounseUp(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let sel = window.getSelection && window.getSelection();
        if(!sel.isCollapsed){
            console.log('Moved Up')


        }
    }
    onMouseDwn(e){


        let sel = window.getSelection && window.getSelection();
        if(!sel.isCollapsed){
            console.log('Moved Down')
        }
    }
    getSelectionHtml() {
        let html = "";
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            let sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                let container = document.createElement("div");
                for (let i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                    container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
                }
                html = container.innerHTML;
            }
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
            if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
                html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
            }
        }

        console.log('html',html)
        return html;

    }
    lastCharRTL(txt) {
        return /[\u0591-\u07FF\uFB1D-\uFDFD\uFE70-\uFEFC]$/.test(txt);
    }

    triggerAlltime(e){
        // console.log('Some Thinms')
        if(!window.getSelection().isCollapsed){
            //find the Direction Of Slelection
            let sel = window.getSelection();
            console.log(sel)
            let range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
            let backwards = range.collapsed;
            range.detach();
            // get selection rects
            let rects = sel.getRangeAt(0).getClientRects();
            let n = rects.length - 1;
            let display = 'block';
            console.log(this.lastCharRTL(this.getSelectionHtml()))
            if (this.lastCharRTL(this.getSelectionHtml()))
                this.setState({
                   display:'none',
                    diplayForDown:'none',
                   top: rects[n].top + 10,
                   left: rects[n].left - 10
               })
            else if (backwards)
                this.setState({
                    display,
                    diplayForDown:'none',
                    top: rects[0].top + -68,
                    left: rects[0].left



                })
            else
                this.setState({
                    display:'none',
                    diplayForDown:'block',
                    top: rects[n].top + 40,
                    left: rects[n].right+-160

                })


        }else{
            this.setState({

                display:'none',
                diplayForDown:'none',


            })
        }
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div  className="container">
                <div className="CenterCon">
                    <div contentEditable="true"  onMouseUp={this.triggerAlltime} onMouseDown={this.triggerAlltime} onKeyUp={this.triggerAlltime} onKeyDown={this.triggerAlltime} className="Edithis" >
                    <p>Test</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style={{top: this.state.top, bottom: this.state.bottom, left:this.state.left, right:this.state.right, display: this.state.display}} className="Toggle">
                    <ul>
                        <li>B</li>
                        <li>U</li>
                        <li>H</li>
                        <li>"</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className="triangle">

                    </div>
                </div>

               {/*DownWard Toggle*/}

                <div style={{top: this.state.top, bottom: this.state.bottom, left: this.state.left, right: this.state.right, display: this.state.diplayForDown}} className="ToggleForDownWardSelection">
                    <div className="triangle-bottom" />
                    <ul>
                        <li>B</li>
                        <li>U</li>
                        <li>H</li>
                        <li>li</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            </div>

        )
    }
}

render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: What browser are you in because this fiddle correctly adds the toggle div for me in both directions.. http://jsfiddle.net/vCwwN/2/ - works for me in GC and FF

Comment: It will work .But try it Select the last line of the content see what happens if it work pls post the screenshot @Zze

Comment: @Alex.S was right in his comment on your answer. I didn't see the issue, because I didn't have to scroll to get to the bottom paragraph. Glad you found your solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `#pointer` is set to absolute position, but when the content is long and scrollable, the top distance is calculated from top of window rather than top of the content.

Adding `height: 100vh` would solve this problem, but you may see two scroll bars in some cases.

Another way is to add `window.pageYOffset` when calculating the `top` of pointer div.

```
if (backwards) {
    $('#pointer').css({top: rects[0].top + window.pageYOffset + 10, left: rects[0].left - 10}).show();
} else {
    $('#pointer').css({top: rects[n].top + window.pageYOffset + 10, left: rects[n].right}).show();
}
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vCwwN/3/)

Answer (score 3):

```js
const isBackwards = () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset);
  range.setEnd(selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset);

  let backwards = range.collapsed;
  range.detach();
  return backwards;
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

At Last I find the answer,I fixed it apply simple style to the contentEditable div
And It it is Working like a Charm.I don't know why it is working But i doubt
window API

```
 <div contentEditable="true" style={{height:'100vh',overflow:'auto'}} onMouseUp={this.triggerAlltime} onMouseDown={this.triggerAlltime} onKeyUp={this.triggerAlltime} onKeyDown={this.triggerAlltime} className="Edithis" >
                    <p>Test</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: The issue is that the `#pointer` is set to absolute position, but when the content is long and scrollable, the `top` distance is calculated from top of window rather than top of the content. Adding `height: 100vh` would solve this problem, but you may see two scroll bars in some cases. Another way is to add `window.pageYOffset` to the `top` of pointer div. Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vCwwN/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. Probably you can check mouse press and unpress events locations and determine initial/end positions to determine whether it was forward or backward selection.

Comment: Well that is a good Idea,Could You Please Show an example with my problem

Comment: I tried it But it is kinda confusing.Could you pls post the code

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title - checking if selection was forward or backwards:

window.getSelection() returns a Selection object and in the documentation you can read the following:

- Selection.anchorNode: Returns the Node in which the selection begins.

However, when you call Selection.getRangeAt(0) on this Selection object, you get instead the selection as Range. Range does not have anchor (and focus) but instead startContainer and endContainer.

- Range.startContainer: Returns the Node within which the Range starts.
- Range.endContainer: Returns the Node within which the Range ends.

Basically the anchordNode is always the Node where the selection started by the user while startContainer is always the first Node in the DOM tree of the selection. So:

- If the anchorNode and the anchorOffset of the selection corresponds with the startContainer and startOffset of the Range, you have (normal) forward selection
- If the anchorNode and the anchorOffset of the selection corresponds with the endContainer and endOffset of the Range, you have backwards selection

(do check in the beginning off course if the selection is collapsed or not)